# Finding unique values and their Maximum.

Tags: excel, vba

I've Data in 4 columns A2:D10.

COL A is list of Cities are in Multiple, in Col B, C & D are their corresponding values.

I'm looking for VBA Code to find unique values in Col A and their Maximum amount in other columns.

I've used `Max(if(A2:A10, A15, B2:D10))`

also,

```
Dim Result As Double
Result = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(customers=mycriteria,Totals)")
```

But unable to execute with Loop.

Expecting help on the issue.

Comment: Try a pivot table.

Comment: Should be pretty simple in VBA code, but as @ScottCraner stated, a pivot table might suit your case better. If it really needs to be a solution in VBA, what exactly was your problem that you refer to with "But unable to execute with Loop"? Show your code that contained said loops. Expecting answer on the comment.

Comment: Finally I got the solution, this code creates Unique values in Col A & finds corresponding Maximum values also,,. 


Sub UniqeMAX() 

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dn As Range

Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng

If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then

.Add Dn.Value, Dn(, 3)
Else
.Item(Dn.Value) = Application.max(.Item(Dn.Value), Dn(, 3))

End If
Next

Range("B1").Resize(.Count, 3) = Application.Transpose(Array(.Keys, .Items))

End With
End Sub